# VBA conditional programming subtleties

Tags: excel, vba

Like anyone who works with conditional formatting but also does a lot of copy and pasting, I'm really sick of the many rules on my sheet multiplying just because I copy pasted some cells. so my thoughts were that I should hard code the conditional formatting and then just make a macro to clear all of the formatting and reapply it. Alas VBA seems to hate me today!

Why doesn't this work:

```
Sheets("Log").Cells.FormatConditions.Delete
With Range("D1:H63")
    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
      "=D1='Working')"
    With .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count)
        .SetFirstPriority
        With .Interior
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 5287936
            .TintAndShade = 0
        End With
    End With
End With
```

When this example I got from elsewhere on SO does:

```
With Range("B3:H63")
        .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
          "=IF($D3="""",FALSE,IF($F3>=$E3,TRUE,FALSE))"
        With .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count)
            .SetFirstPriority
            With .Interior
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .Color = 5287936
                .TintAndShade = 0
            End With
        End With
    End With
```

Answer (score 2):

I see two problems with that code:

First, in

```
.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
      "=D1='Working')"
```

you have a stray `)` which should be eliminated

Second, `'Working'` isn't a valid literal in the formula but you could quote it

Like this:

```
.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
      "=D1=""'Working'"""
```

That works in the sense that it inserts conditional formats in the cells without throwing a run-time error. Whether or not it inserts the format you want triggered by the condition you want is a separate question which I can't answer based on the information that you provided.